# EditorGUILayout.TextField not returning updated inputText

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple window where I want to print to console the value the user writes in the text field of said window when a button is pressed. The text printed to console is always the default one (abcd) even if I change it. Another thing I detected is that when I change the text in the text field and press the return button it changes back to the default value again.

Why is `inputText` value always the default one? How can I make this work correctly?

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PhraseAccept : EditorWindow
{
    public string editorWindowText = "Write your text here: ";
    string newProjectName = "abcd";
    int projectNumber = 1;

    void OnGUI()
    {
        string inputText = "";
        inputText = EditorGUILayout.TextField(editorWindowText, newProjectName);
        this.Repaint();

        if (GUILayout.Button("OK"))
            Debug.Log(inputText);

        if (GUILayout.Button("Abort"))
            Close();
    }

    [MenuItem("Tools/PhraseAccept2")]
    public static void main()
    {
        EditorWindow window = GetWindow(typeof(PhraseAccept));
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this:

```
newProjectName = EditorGUILayout.TextField(editorWindowText, newProjectName);
```

Also you are setting `inputText` equal to null everytime `OnGUI` is called which could be multiple times.

Comment: why is that? I am printing the value of inputText and not newProjectName

Comment: Print out `newProjectName` instead.